# JOINing tables while ignoring duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

So, let's say I have a hash/relational table that connects users, teams a user can join, and challenges in which teams participate (`teams_users_challenges`), as well as a table that stores entered data for all users in a given challenge (`entry_data`). I want to get the average scores for each user in the challenge (the average value per day in a given week). However, there is a chance that a user will somehow join more than one team erroneously (which shouldn't happen, but does on occasion). Here is the SQL query below that gets a particular user's score:

```
SELECT tuc.user_id, SUM(ed.data_value) / 7 as value
FROM teams_users_challenges tuc
LEFT JOIN entry_data ed ON (
    tuc.user_id = ed.user_id AND
    ed.entry_date BETWEEN '2013-09-16' AND '2013-09-22'
)
WHERE tuc.challenge_id = ___
AND tuc.user_id = ___
```

If a user has mistakenly joined more than one team, (s)he would have more than one entry in `teams_users_challenges`, which would essentially duplicate the data retrieved. So if a user is on 3 different teams for the same challenge, (s)he would have 3 entries in `teams_users_challenges`, which would multiply their average `value` by 3, thanks to the `LEFT JOIN` that automatically takes in all records, and not just one.

I've tried using `GROUP BY`, but that doesn't seem to restrict the data to only one instances within `teams_users_challenges`. Does anybody have any ideas as to how I could restrict the query to only take in one record within `teams_users_challenges`?

**ADDENDUM:** The columns within `teams_users_challenges` are `team_id`, `user_id`, and `challenge_id`.

Comment: Join with a subquery that uses `GROUP BY` or `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a new empty table, you can express your 'business rule' that a user should only join one team per challenge as a `unique` constraint in SQL:

```
alter table teams_users_challenges
add constraint oneUserPerTeamPerChallenge
unique (
  user_id
, team_id
, challenge_id
);
```

If you can't change the table, you'll need to group by user and team and pick a single challenge from each group in the query result. Maybe pick just the latest challenge.

Comment: This was perfect! All I had to do was `GROUP BY tuc.user_id, tuc.team_id` and made sure I selected a `DISTINCT tuc.user_id`, and it strips out the duplicates. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it, but if you can't clean up the data as Yawar suggested, try:

```
SELECT tuc.user_id, SUM(ed.data_value) / 7 as value
FROM entry_data ed
LEFT JOIN
(
select tuc.user_id, tuc.challenge_id from teams_users_challenges tuc group by tuc.user_id, tuc.challenge_id
) AS SINGLE_TEAM
 ON SINGLE_TEAM.user_id = ed.user_id AND
    ed.entry_date BETWEEN '2013-09-16' AND '2013-09-22'
WHERE tuc.challenge_id = ___
AND tuc.user_id = ___
```